# iPhone5 not making data connection with phonegap

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, navigator

I'm using phonegap to check if there is an internet connection

```
if(navigator.connection.type !== Connection.NONE){ ..do an ajax call
```

This works fine in android but in iPhone5, when the WiFi is turned off I just get `connection = none` and that's it...android at least goes into 3G and does the call.

What am I doing wrong?
Do I have to force iPhone5 to use the data connection and if so how?
As I said, both work fine if there is a WiFi connection.

Answer (score 0):

try to scan all connection

```
function checkConnection() {
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

if(states[networkState]=='No network connection'){
alert("no connection");

}
if(states[networkState]=='Cell 3G connection'){
//do something

}
...
...
}
```

for check all connection you can try

```
if(states[networkState]=='No network connection'){
alert("no connection");

}else{
//do something
}
```